# R-Dplyr - Conditionally Count same column in dataframe (in summarize of group by)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data-frame that gets generated by query (hard coded sql query into R Script). I then group-by and summarize to get min/max/count of observations for each staff member. What I would like to do is know, for each Staff member, the number (or better the proportion) of observations that have another column (shift ratio) within 5% of 1.00 (IE 0.95 <= Shift Ratio <= 1.05).

Created a mock-up as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

Roll_Number <- c("1234567", "111111111", "222222222", "333333333", "444444444", "555555555", "666666666", "777777777")

Shift_Ratio <- c("1.05", "0.99", "1.45", "1.02", "0.97", "1.01", "0.97", "1.24")

Staff <- c("John", "John", "John", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave", "Dave")

Shift_Data <- data.frame(Roll_Number, Shift_Ratio, Staff)


SummaryStats <- Shift_Data %>% group_by (`Staff`) %>%
 dplyr::summarize( 'Number of Accounts' = n(),
                   'Within 5%' = sum(`Shift_Ratio`[`Shift_Ratio` <= 1.05])

 )
```

I've attempted with n, trying to filter/summarize etc with no luck yet. I've seen and done where it filters on one column and applies aggregate functions such as below, just not sure how to filter for both sides of the condition. Attempts with between(Shift Ratio, 0.95, 1.05) did not work. I've avoided filtering before the summarize call, though I guess I could perhaps break the process into two steps and filter-count for totals then left-join that summary onto a master summary that totaled items with no filters. Just hoping there is a more graceful method I am missing. Any advice is appreciated.

```
'Exempt Value' = sum(as.numeric(as.character(`Current Year Value`)) [`Tax Status` == "Exempt"], na.rm=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift_Ratio` column is of class 'character', so no mathematical operation would work on it. We use `type.convert` to convert all the columns in `Shift_Data` to the relevant class and calculate the percentage of each `Staff` being in 5% range from 1.

```
library(dplyr)

Shift_Data %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Staff) %>%
  summarise(Number_of_Accounts = n(),
            Within_5_perc = mean(between(Shift_Ratio, 0.95, 1.05)) * 100)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  Staff Number_of_Accounts Within_5_perc
#  <chr>              <int>         <dbl>
#1 Dave                   5          80  
#2 John                   3          66.7
```

Comment: Type.convert(as.is) is amazing! I do have some null's in my actual dataset, and I get an error in size for the between command. Can I use na.rm = T? I tried it in the mean() function but that didnt work. Can between() accept na.rm or something similar? Didnt look like it in the spec I saw. Will mark as answer shortly because you fairly solved the issue posted and helped teach the convert. Thanks!

Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 61

Comment: @SMS Do you have `NULL` or `NA`s ? You can remove them using `filter` or add `na.rm = TRUE` in `mean`.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with something that followed, was attempting to use arrange but that had issues (likely type conversion related). The 5% code worked both by my pseudo re-prex and in my larger code. thank you for the assistance!